# Deployment error on Glassfish V2.1 but not glassfish V3.0

Tags: spring, rest, glassfish

We are using Hibernate, Spring and RESTful web services in out project. Our WAR file deployment succeed on Glassfish V3 but when we try to deploy it on Glassfish V2.1, it gives following exception. What could be error?

Thanks in advance.

```
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.EnumConstantNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
        ... 97 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.EnumConstantNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseEnumArray(AnnotationParser.java:673)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:462)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:286)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:222)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:69)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:52)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.declaredAnnotations(Method.java:695)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.getAnnotation(Method.java:679)
        at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.isAnnotationPresent(AccessibleObject.java:168)
        at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaAnnotationReader.isAnnotationPresent(JavaAnnotationReader.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXAnnotatedElement.isAnnotationPresent(JavaXAnnotatedElement.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.mustBeSkipped(AnnotationBinder.java:1111)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.addProperty(AnnotationBinder.java:1091)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.addElementsOfAClass(AnnotationBinder.java:1038)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.getElementsToProcess(AnnotationBinder.java:859)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:667)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.processArtifactsOfType(AnnotationConfiguration.java:546)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:291)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1162)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:717)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that your application uses Java EE 6 functionality that comes with Glassfish 3 but not with Glassfish 2.1 (Java EE 5).

See [this link for a comparison of both versions](http://glassfish.java.net/public/comparing_v2_and_v3.html#2).